# Nexus repository don't mirror jasperreports 5.0.0 jar

Tags: jasper-reports, nexus

I'm trying to setup a nexus repository for maven projects. 
I have nexus working and I've created a simple maven project in eclipse. It seems ok.

The problem is that when I add jasperreports 5.0.0 dependency in my pom.xml maven is not downloading the jar.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

I've added http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/ as a proxy repository to nexus and i configured it as a member of the public group, but nothing happens.

This is my maven settings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>E:\mavenRep\repository</localRepository>
  <mirrors>
   <mirror>
      <id>NexusEGEA</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Nexus en la máquina de desarrollo de EGEA.</name>
      <url>http://geades.adm.es/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors> 

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>NexusEGEA</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://geades.adm.es/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://geades.adm.es/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>NexusEGEA</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

[Edited for adding nexus information]

When browsing the public index on the nexus admin application I don`t see de jar file. I only see jasperreports-5.0.0-javadoc.jar , jasperreports-5.0.0-sources.jar and jasperreports-5.0.0.pom under net.sf.jasperreports.jasperreports.5.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

That repository does not contain the dependency you asked for. `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.0.0` should be in http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.0.0, but that just doesn't exist.

That said, the artifact you look for [is on central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.jasperreports%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jasperreports%22), and should be available from your company Nexus by default.

Comment: I've solve the problem uploading the file jasperreports-5.0.0.jar to the 3rd party repository in nexus.
I don't know why maven can't download the file from the central repository in nexus, but now I can deploy the project.

If anyone knows de reason more answers will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.